# When is Virial theorem applicable for superposition of energy eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, virial-theorem

In a note I recently studied, it states that:

> "All energy eigenstates of harmonic oscillator obey the Virial Theorem, but this theorem does not apply to superpositions of energy eigenstates except for certain particular cases."

So, what are the "certain cases"?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which note?

Comment: Related: [Average Energy of the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78952/)